# NumericUpDown defaulting to value assigned at design time

Tags: vb.net, application-settings, numericupdown

I'm using a NumericUpDown control with minimum set to 1 and maximum set to 60 (the value is used for setting display timeout of a form). When it is changed during runtime, it is bound to an Application setting and saved. On Form Load, I am attempting to set the value of the NumericUpDown control to the value stored in that setting (8 for example). No matter what though, it doesn't use the setting's value, it uses the value of the value property set at the design time of the NumericUpDown control.
The value set at design time is 2.

Here's the code used to send value from NumericUpDown control to the settings:

```
Private Sub NumericUpDownOSD_Hide_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NumericUpDownOSD_Hide.ValueChanged
    My.Settings.NotificationDisplayDuration = NumericUpDownOSD_Hide.Value
End Sub
```

Here's the code used to assign value from setting to the NumericUpDown control when the form loads

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    NumericUpDownOSD_Hide.Value = My.Settings.NotificationDisplayDuration
End Sub
```

Comment: The ValueChanged event will also fire when the control is first initialized, usually by the form's InitializeComponent() method.  Which will overwrite the saved My.Settings value.  Easy to see with the debugger btw, simply set breakpoints on both statements.

Comment: @HansPassant ok got it. Now I got to know the cause of the problem. Know any way to solve it?

Comment: Just do the obvious thing, save the value before you call InitializeComponent(), restore it afterwards.  VB.NET programmers don't use Sub New often enough, perhaps.  And consider that setting the default value in the designer was a bad idea since you always restore it from the setting.  Settings have a default value as well.

Comment: @HansPassant How do I save the value before calling  InitializeComponent() and restore it afterwards? I'm new to vb .net, can you please give me the code to do that